# Error with JQuery validation in File and Select input element

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, validation

I have some problem about highlighting an error in bootstrap using JQuery Validation plugin. It work great on normal input, but when i'm using select and file type element the error highlight is not showing. it show only when i click browse on file type and try to select some option on select type. here's my Form:

```
<!-- form start -->
                    <form class="form-horizontal" id="saveForm" method="get" action="" >
                        <div class="box-body">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="nama" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Nama</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-10">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Your full name" name="nama" minlength="2" required>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="email" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>

                                <div class="col-sm-10">
                                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Your Email" required>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="exampleInputFile" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Images</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-10">
                                    <input type="file" id="images" required>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="tipe" class="col-sm-2 control-label">User Type</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-10">
                                    <select id="tipe" class="form-control" required>
                                        <option value="">Please select user type</option>
                                        <option value="admin">Admin</option>
                                        <option value="member">Member</option>
                                        <option value="publisher">Publisher</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /.box-body -->
                        <div class="box-footer">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</button>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info pull-right">Save</button>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /.box-footer -->
                    </form>
```

and here is my Jquery code:

```
$.validator.setDefaults({
    submitHandler: function() {
        alert("submitted!");
    },
    highlight: function(element) {
        $(element).closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
    },
    unhighlight: function(element) {
        $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
    },
    errorElement: 'span',
    errorClass: 'help-block',
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        if (element.parent('.input-group').length) {
            error.insertAfter(element.parent());
        } else {
            error.insertAfter(element);
        }
    }
});
$().ready(function() {
    // validate the comment form when it is submitted

    $("#saveForm").validate({
        rules: {
            nama: {
                minlength: 2,
                required: true
            },
            email: {
                email: true,
                required: true
            },
            tipe: {
                required: true,
                minimum: 1
            },
            images: {
                required: true
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: need to write required class and show us have you included all required js

Comment: and method post for form

Comment: @Rush.2707 i think the problem is not about the required js, it work fine with name and email field. but it doesn't work on images and select input type.

Comment: validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'Please select an image'
                    },
                    file: {
                        extension: 'jpeg,jpg,png',
                        type: 'image/jpeg,image/png',
                        maxSize: 2097152,   // 2048 * 1024
                        message: 'The selected file is not valid'
                    }
                }

Comment: should try it .... must work

Comment: @Rush.2707 it doesn't work, i'm not sure but i think it's about the errors placement or something.